# Car radio stopped working

Tags: electrical, mazda, audio, protege

Hi I'm 16 years old and have just bought my first car. It's a 2001 Mazda protoge. Today while I was driving I plugged in a USB charger for my phone and the radio shut off. Now the radio won't turn on and the outlet for the USB charger doesn't work. I have no idea what happened. Could anyone explain?

Comment: You're lucky it wasn't the cylinder head gasket.

Comment: Check the fuse.

Comment: What else could be the problem if all the fuse is working

Answer (score 1):

OK so it blew a 15 amp fuse. Thanks for the help. I also want to know how it blew a 15 amp fuse so next time it won't happen. Does the radio actually draw that much current? Or did I short circuit the outlet by plugging the USB charger in? If you could help me figure out why it happened that would be great.

Comment: Where did you plug USB charger, Is it to a USB port or to the cigarette lighter via USB adapter.

Comment: Cigarette lighter

Comment: I recently plugged cheap cigarette lighter/USB charger and had issues. I believe the charger is defective.

Comment: OK so if I get a good quality charger I should be fine?

Comment: You will have to try, It should work fine, I believe

Comment: Mazda has the cig lighter AND the radio on the same fuse? A 15 at that? My Toyota has a dedicated 10 for the fuse and 15 for the radio.

Comment: Yeah I was surprised too, but it's a first car so I'm not really complaining